# receive Array of hashes in API call rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I 'm working on rails app in which I need to receive array of hashes in API call with Grape like.

```
{   
  tournament_id:1       
  match_id: 10
  [     
    {           
        team_id: 1                  
        score: 10   
     },     
     {          
        team_id: 2          
        score: 20   
      }
    ]
  }
```

so that I can receive score of each team in single call for a specific match and tournament instead of multiple calls for score of each team.

I have tried multiple things like

```
    group :teams_with_scores, type: Array, desc: "An array of Teams with scores" do
          requires :team_id, type: String,desc: "Team ID"
          requires :score, type: String,desc: "Score"
    end
```

But don't have a clue that how to do it.

Comment: 14 views and not even a comment,
at least, guide me towards right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send this data as a json string, and then parse this json when you get it:

```
params do
  scores_info, type: String, desc: 'the scores info'
end
get do
  scores_info = JSON.parse(params[:scores_info])
end
```

Comment: Its been a while but exactly used this.